# How to add multiple class in criteria to check a column

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Here is the above code, I just want to add country class to the criteria such that if the deleteflag in country class is false, it should not fetch the states in staveprovince class:

```
public List<StateProvince> getAllState(Country country)throws HibernateException,ConstraintViolationException {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StateProvince.class);
        criteria.setCacheable(true);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country", country));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("deleteFlag", false));
        return criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Please let me know the mapping. Does StateProvince contain Country in it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `country` is an attribute of `StateProvince` of type `Country`, so in that case your criteria must be the following:

```
criteria.createCriteria("country").add(Restrictions.eq("deleteFlag", false));
```

Comment: i got the answer which i want please

Comment: It will not check the stateprovince deleteflag

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have Country associated in StateProvince. Please comment if this does not solve your problem.

```
public List<StateProvince> getAllState(Country country)throws HibernateException,ConstraintViolationException {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StateProvince.class);
        criteria.createAlias("country", "country");
        criteria.setCacheable(true);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(deleteFlag", false));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country", country));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country.deleteFlag", false));
        return criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got answer please check it... I got the output which i expect

Comment: In your code it check only the delete flage for country class which is in stateprovince. But It retrive all the deleted flage states corresponding to that country

Comment: I think you need to be bit more in details with the specifications.
Just take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

public class StateProvinceDAOImpl implements StateProvinceDAO {

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<StateProvince> getAllState(Country country)throws HibernateException,ConstraintViolationException {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StateProvince.class,"state");
        criteria.setCacheable(true);
        criteria.createAlias("state.country", "country");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("state.deleteFlag", "country.deleteFlag"));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country", country));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("deleteFlag", false));
        return criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work unless you specify `country.deleteFlag` !!!
Are you sure your code is running without error?

Comment: yes its running correctly. i pass the country in in the url like http://localhost:8080/provhrmapp/service/State?countryId=11